# Addition of fractions with different powers of variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Subtract $\dfrac{2}{5x^2}$ from $\dfrac 3{4x}$.

My book says that it gives $\dfrac 7{20x}$ answer. But i don't understand that if these two fractions have variables which have different powers then how can we add them?

For example, we can't add $2x + 3x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the square power of $x$ in $\frac{2}{5x^2}$ is misprinted in your book.

Because for $$\frac{3}{4x}-\frac{2}{5x} =\frac{15x-8x}{20x^2}=\frac{7}{20x}$$ which is the answer given in your book.

Comment: yes, i think it has been misprinted. Well, it must be misprinted because otherwise we can't calculate anything.

Comment: We can bring to a common denominator and calculate, we just don't het the answer supplied.

Answer (score 4):

We have, essentially, $$\dfrac 3{4x} - \dfrac{2}{5x^2}$$

Find the common denominator:

$$\dfrac {3\cdot 5x - 4\cdot 2}{20x^2} = \dfrac{15x - 8}{20x^2}$$

**Note**: There may have been a misprint in the problem statement.

To obtain an answer of $\dfrac 7{20x}$ would require we subtract $\dfrac 2{5x}$ from $\dfrac 3{4x}$. But in that case, the *principle* is the same: find the common denominator and subtract: $$\dfrac 3{4x} - \dfrac 2{5x} = \dfrac{3\cdot 5 - 4\cdot 2}{20x} = \dfrac{7}{20x}$$

Comment: needs another TU and CONGRATS 80K - wow! You earned it! :-)